# Ocamldoc and open modules

Tags: ocaml, ocamldoc

I'm trying to document a small project of mine using ocamldoc.
I have one main `.ml` file which `opens` two others `.ml` files.

```
$ ocamldoc -html included1.ml included2.ml
```

Works just fine, but when I add the including file, like

```
$ ocamldoc -html included1.ml included2.ml including.ml
```

I get this:

```
File "including.ml", line 5, characters 5-16:
Error: Unbound module Included1
1 error(s) encountered
```

I see from the [ocamldoc documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/ocamldoc.html#sec333) that opening modules is perfectly fine, until no conflict arises.
How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine for a module to use other modules however it needs to be able to see the compiled interfaces for those. So in your case you first need to compile the `.ml` files to generate `.cmi` files. Then you need to indicate to ocamldoc where these files are. So something like this should do:

```
ocamlc -c included1.ml
ocamlc -c included2.ml
ocamlc -c -I . including.ml
ocamldoc -html -I . included1.ml included2.ml including.ml
```

Note that in general it's a good (essential) practice to create `.mli` files for each of your modules an document and `ocamldoc` these rather than the `.ml` files.

Comment: damn, just wrote the same answer :) Btw, the `-I .` is not needed, as it will look in the current directory by default.

Comment: Sorry... Yeah that `-I .` may not be needed I think there's a tool in the toolchain were it's needed but I never remember which one (or maybe I dreamt).

Comment: Oh, ok... I thought it was only for external dependencies, and not for files in the same directory and included in the list! =) Thank you!